# ASP.NET Web API: RC to RTM change. Sending content using HttpContext ends in a NoContent status

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5, c#-5.0

Since ASP.NET Web API RC I was using some approach based on declaring void API controller's operations.

I was customizing a <strike>response object</strike> DTO (instead of using HttpResponseMessage) using AOP and PostSharp, and finally this was sent to the client using `HttpContext.Response.Write(...)` serializing the DTO into a JSON string.

When I upgraded my solution to ASP.NET Web API RTM, this approach didn't work anymore.

Whenever I send a response from the Web API and I receive it in the client-side, I find that the response is sent with a 204 status (NoContent) while I was setting a 200 status (OK) for the response itself.

Because this approach was working in the RC version of WebAPI I suspect that's an unknown breaking change when WebAPI development team transitioned to RTM version.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, since RTM if a POST action does not return an HttpResponseMessage the default status code is 204 (and not 200 as was back in RC). There are two things, I know, we can do to keep clients from complaining about 204.

a) Change the response message from within your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage DoWork(MyModel model)
{
   // Do work
   return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new ObjectContent<MyModel>(model, FormatterConfig.JsonFormatter) };
}
```

b) Change the response in a DelegatingHandler (dirty by generic way)

```
public class ResponseHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        response.Result.StatusCode = response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode ? System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK : response.Result.StatusCode;
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Your answer is useful! Sadly (or hopefully) I've changed my code base in order to work better with WebAPI RTM. Best of all is I have "void operations" yet, and I let WebAPI create the standard ResponseMessage, while I set message content, headers and/or code in a filter OnActionExecuted. But I'll look forward for a DelegatingHandler, which could be helpful in other situations without creating filters!

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of such breaking change but I can confirm that this doesn't work in the RTM. Anyway, that's such a wrong approach of using the Web API that it's probably a good thing that it doesn't work. You are killing the whole point of the Web API if you are going to manually write the response to the client. If you have some existing code that does this that you cannot modify then I would recommend you using a Generic ASHX handler until you are ready to upgrade.

Comment: Well, it's a way of customizing it. I suspect that's a breaking change, because if I refactor an operation to return my custom object, it works. What's more strange is the approach doesn't work for content, but HTTP headers are being sent yet by using HttpContext!

Comment: Could you show some code and explain what the expected result is? Maybe there are better ways to achieve whatever you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It's an API made from scratch, I'm just in its first states. I don't think this kills the point of WebAPI. The point is a Web Service infrastructure that's easy to configure and it's not a pain like previous ones using WCF. In addition, it's REST-friendly. I tend to use tools "as is" if I think that "as is" works for me. But if I need to get the best of the tool and make some additions, I've no problems with mixing official approaches + my own ones.

Comment: Alright, so are you willing to share some code so that we could have a constructive discussion about something specific?

Comment: In the other hand, I know how to change this to the official approach. The point of my question is if this is a known breaking change or not :D

Comment: I believe it'd be hard to share code since there's some AOP in this approach. But, at the end of the day, it's as simple as I've a DTO which is built during the processing of the request and it's serialized just before giving a response to the client.

Comment: You said something about an Action Filter in your question without the PostSharp step. Could you show this and explain what you are trying to achieve? Without having specific code it's hard to say what exactly might have changed since the RC.

Comment: I find you've curiosity on this topic. I'm translating the PostSharp aspect into a full WebAPI filter and make use of HttpResponseMessage. With my question, I was trying to find if some other had the same problem. You said that you had it or you've checked that I'm not wrong, and for me, it's everything I need right now :)

Comment: I've updated my question in order to be more accurate. BTW, I believe your answer, skipping the part of an ASHX, it's ok for me.